# Paypal's WSDL file not valid anymore?

Tags: php, soap, paypal, soap-client

After 2-3 years of using Paypal API, SoapClient fails to load WSDL

> Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'https://www.paypalobjects.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl' : Start tag expected, '<'
>   not found in .../paypal.php on line 52

**WSDL file:** https://www.paypalobjects.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl

It fails to parse wsdl on three different computers

Is it SoapClient fault? Or WSDL is invalid? How to fix it? Some validators says XML/WSDL is OK, some validators says is not ok...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

SoapClient fails to parse the wsdl file when HTTP response headers are incorrect.

Since today Paypal sends `Content-Type: text/html` for wsdl file in HTTP response so I just copied wsdl/xsd files to my server and everything is OK again...

**EDIT:** now (17 Apr) it looks like paypal is sending file using `text/plain`